# How to know that a particular kernel is linux based or not?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am using the real time kernel embedded. In the kernel documentation it is not listed that it is either linux based or on any other. How do i know that a particular kernel i am using is linux based kernel or not? I want know what characteristics/features of a kernel, we compare, to know on which it is based.

Comment: What kind of device is running this kernel? Do you have access to a shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`uname` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/uname.html) (or the [`uname` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/uname.html)) to find out the name and version of the operating system (kernel) you're using.

In the former case, `uname -s` will report `Linux` for a Linux kernel; in the latter case, inspect the `sysname` member of your `struct utsname`.